# wrapping commands through ssh: how to manage complex quotes?

Tags: bash, ssh, google-bigquery, double-quotes, single-quotes

I use an HPC cluster. The compute nodes can't have access to internet, only the frontal.

So I want to wrap all the commands that need to access internet in order to execute them on the frontal.

ex: for wget

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh frontal /bin/wget "$@"
```

-> works fine

I have to wrap this bq (google BigQuery) command:
`bq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '2016%' AND mgrs_tile == '32ULU' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;"`

I managed to requote the command and to launch it successfully on CLI:
`ssh frontal '~/downloads_and_builds/builds/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '"'"'2016%'"'"' AND mgrs_tile == '"'"'32ULU'"'"' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;"'`

Now I want to write a wrapper named bq able to get the parameters and launch this command through ssh ... here is what i have tried :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

# all parameters in an array
args=("$@")

# unset globing (there's a * in the SELECT clause)
set -f

# managing inner quotes
arg2=`echo "${args[2]}" | perl -pe 's/'\''/'\''"'\''"'\''/g'`

# put back double quotes (") suppressed by bash
args="${args[0]} ${args[1]} \"${arg2}\""

# build command with parameters
cmd="~/downloads_and_builds/builds/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq $args"

echo ""
echo "command without external quotes"
echo "$cmd"
echo ""

echo "testing it ..."
ssh hpc-login1 "$cmd"
echo ""

# wrapping command between simple quotes (like on the CLI)
cmd="'"'~/downloads_and_builds/builds/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq '"$args""'"
echo "commande with external quotes"
echo "$cmd"
echo ""

echo "testing it ..."
ssh hpc-login1 $cmd
echo "done"
```

Here is the output of this script:
    $ bq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '2016%' AND mgrs_tile == '32ULU' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;"

```
command without external quotes
~/downloads_and_builds/builds/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '"'"'2016%'"'"' AND mgrs_tile == '"'"'32ULU'"'"' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;"

testing it ...
Waiting on bqjob_r102b0c22cdd77c2d_000001629b8391a3_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   

commande with external quotes
'~/downloads_and_builds/builds/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '"'"'2016%'"'"' AND mgrs_tile == '"'"'32ULU'"'"' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;"'

testing it ...
bash: ~/downloads_and_builds/builds/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '2016%' AND mgrs_tile == '32ULU' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type (in english: no file or directory of this kind)
```

As you can see, I managed to get a correct command string, just like the one which works on CLI, but it doesn't work in my script:

1. The first attempt succeeded but gives no output (I have tried to redirect it in a file: the file were created but is empty)
2. In the second attempt (with external simple quotes, just like the CLI command that worked), bash take the quoted arg as a block and don't find the command ...

Has somebody an idea on how to launch a complex command (with quotes, wildcards ...) like this one through ssh using a wrapper script ?

(ie. **one** wrapper named foo able to replace a foo command and execute it correctly through ssh with the arguments provided)

Comment: Is reading the query from a file not an option? `bq query < query_text.sql`. It would be better not to mess with escaping at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` has the same semantics as `eval`: all arguments are concatenated with spaces and then evaluated as a shell command.

You can have it work with `execve` semantics (like sudo) by having a wrapper escape the arguments:

```
remotebq() { 
  ssh yourhost "~/downloads_and_builds/builds/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq $(printf '%q ' "$@")"
}
```

This quotes thoroughly and consistently, so you no longer have to worry about adding additional escaping. It'll run exactly what you tell it (as long as your remote shell is `bash`):

```
remotebq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '2016%' AND mgrs_tile == '32ULU' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;"
```

However, the downside to running exactly what you tell it is that now you need to know exactly what you want to run.

For example, you can no longer pass `'~/foo'` as an argument because this is not a valid file: `~` is a shell feature and not a directory name, and when it's correctly escaped it will not be replaced by your home directory.

Comment: Excellent ! It solves completely my problem !
printf '%q' ... I didn't know it.
That's the trick I wanted to know for years, thanks a lot ! And thanks too for advices about ~

Comment: @DuGNu please accept this answer if it helped you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The basic way to do this, using *shell here doc*   :

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -t server<<'EOF'
bq --format=json query "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '2016%' AND mgrs_tile == '32ULU' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;"
command2
command3
...
EOF
```

Comment: Yes, it could work with the complete path for bq (the wrapper is first in the PATH), but it doen't fix the problem as what you suggest is hard-coded. The request is not the same each time. And you can not put a var in the heredoc section as it is not evaluated

Comment: I use another account, asked to be linked both, still waiting

Comment: @DuGNu If you don't quote the here doc token (i.e. use `EOF` instead of `'EOF'`, then variables will be expanded on the client side. You need to take care to escape any expansions that you want to happen on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are already using Perl so...

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $query = q(SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:cloud_storage_geo_index.sentinel_2_index] WHERE sensing_time LIKE '2016%' AND mgrs_tile == '32ULU' ORDER BY sensing_time ASC LIMIT 1000;);

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
$ssh->system('bq', '--format=json', 'query', $query)
  or die $ssh->error;
```

`Net::OpenSSH` would take care of quoting everything.